# WeChat Rich Media cards, URLs and Google maps

Tags: google-maps, wechat

I've built a Rich Media Card WeChat response to a location event that populates the URL parameter with a Googlemaps URL including the Lat/long values from the location response

like this

```
 $return ='<xml>
             <ToUserName><![CDATA[' . $xml->FromUserName . ']]></ToUserName>
             <FromUserName><![CDATA[' . $xml->ToUserName . ']]></FromUserName>
             <CreateTime>' . mktime() . '</CreateTime>
             <MsgType><![CDATA[news]]></MsgType>
             <ArticleCount>1</ArticleCount>
            <Articles>
             <item>
               <Title><![CDATA[Your Location]]></Title> 
               <Description><![CDATA[Click this card to demonstrate the mapping functionality]]</Description>
               <PicUrl><![CDATA[http://www.foo/WeChat/images/map.png]]></PicUrl>
               <Url><![CDATA[https://www.google.com/maps/@'.$xml->Latitude.','.$xml->Longitude.',13z]]></Url>
            </item>
           </Articles>
        </xml>';
```

The Latitude and longitude variables are populated correctly

If i output the URL it is well formed.
however when  I click the link Wechat opens its browser and attempts to load the URL but no map is displayed.

Is there something I've missed?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All seems good. Tested on IPhone. Ensure it is working on the native browser outside of WeChat. If that is working then please post a screenshot here of what you are seeing in the native browser and in WeChat as well as the final URL